# destroy_all not calling destroy on each object for has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the associations setup in this manner.

```
class Program
  has_many :program_activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recent_activities, through: :program_activities, source: :recent_activity
end

class RecentActivity
  has_many :program_activities, dependent: :destroy        
end
```

I wanted to delete the recent_activities associated with the program object.

```
program.recent_activities.destroy_all
```

But the above query actually just deletes ( please note that deletes and not destroy ) the program_activities and leaves the recent_activities objects alone.

I found this by inspecting the rails console queries, Is there something wrong with the destroy_all method or Have I actually setup the associations incorrectly.

Comment: By looking the rails code, `activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#211`, it calls `delete` method which mean it deletes the records from the database directly. If you want to trigger `destroy`, considering of using `has_many` without `through`. In `activerecord-4.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb#169`, it will call `destory!` method.

Answer (score 0):

to me there's nothing wrong, it's normal in a many-to-many relationship.

if a `recent_activity` was related to one and only one `program`, you shouldn't have a `program_activities` relationship model. you just should have RecentActivity with a `belongs_to :program` and the deletion would work.

in your case, you consider that a `recent_activity` could have many `programs`. so the deletion of a `program` can't delete a `recent_activity` entity because by definition, it can belong to several programs. it will just delete the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong. It's common that you can just delete the association table when you destroy a model row.

Assume this situation:

1. Group has_many group_members
2. Member has_many group_members
3. Group has_many members through group_members
4. Member has_many groups through group_members

Is that meaning when we destroy a group, and the relative members should be destroyed too? They are independent model rows, even there is not any groups. And maybe they are of other groups. If they are cascading destroyed, data table will be messy.

Hope this example can explain the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this recently, and this is what ended up working for me:

```
program.program_activities.each { |activity| activity.recent_activity.destroy }
```

Not exactly concise, but since the destroy_all method doesn't do what you would expect, this may be the best there is.  It does indeed trigger destroy, so in your case, it will take the association with it.  If you *don't* have dependent: :destroy set, you'll get a foreign key violation.